# Windows does not support privileged mode

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux. and I have problems creating a container.

```
docker-compose run --rm --service-ports --use-aliases backend - bash
```

Show me this error

```
ERROR: Cannot create container for service backend: Windows does not support privileged mode
```

I have activated
  "experimental": true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have, in parallel of WSL, a Docker for Windows installed, with the option "Enable Linux Containers on Windows" (LCOW)" active (as in [nodeshift issue 127](https://github.com/nodeshift/nodeshift/issues/127#issuecomment-346983617), that could explained the error message (seen in [`moby#runconfig/hostconfig_windows.go`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/a2f3f6660d08dfb667f091e0fd8454c815dd1c81/runconfig/hostconfig_windows.go#L75-L84))

Double-check your settings, following the "[Setting Up Docker for Windows and WSL to Work Flawlessly](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly)"

> While the Docker daemon cannot run directly on WSL, you can use the Docker CLI to connect to a remote Docker daemon running through Docker for Windows or any other VM you create.

Check also your Windows 10 version: the more recent, the better.