# Error response from daemon: Windows does not support privileged mode

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, kubernetes, zalenium

I have installed the Docker Tool on my Windows 10 Pro machine.

Have pulled below images from Docker Hub:

docker pull elgalu/selenium

docker pull dosel/zalenium

When I am trying to start zalenium with the below command:

```
"docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /c/Users/<username>:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start"
```

I am getting error:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error
>   response from daemon: Windows does not support privileged mode.

I want to start the zalenium with the above command but I could not able to do it, because of this error.

Can anyone assist me on this, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows does not support privileged mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056888/windows-does-not-support-privileged-mode)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have gone through the above one, but no luck.

Comment: What version of Docker are you using? Did you enable "Enable Linux containers onw Windows"? Did you installed it using official docs: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you did not provide enough information. Your Windows version, Docker for Windows version, how did you install it, etc.

Officially `--priviledged` flag is not supported as on the [Github thread](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31059) is already mentioned:

> there is no support for privileged containers on Windows in the platform.

It's also confirmed in [this thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/75132).

In addition, you might check [this thread](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/issues/410). It's the same case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Update on the newest docker version, fixed the issue.